# Even though the fit seems correct, NonlinearModelFit throws a failed convergence error

Tags: fitting, warning-messages, nonlinear

Consider the following data

```
data = {{2, -2.99380668585}, {4, -2.99413053462}, {6, -2.99439488497}, {8, -2.99467836024},
 {10, -2.99491958936}, {12, -2.99519218472}, {14, -2.99538900867}, {16, -2.99562768004}, 
{18, -2.99584876062}, {20, -2.99601713877}, {22, -2.99619549077}, {24, -2.99637350562}}
```

I am trying to fit to this data the (displaced) real part of some powers of a complex number

```
fit = NonlinearModelFit[ data, 
-a + \[Rho] r^m Cos[m \[Phi] + \[Psi]], {a, \[Rho], \[Phi], \[Psi], r},
 m,  MaxIterations -> 1000]
```

Even though the fit looks good

```
DiscretePlot[fit["BestFit"], {m, 2, 24, 2},  Epilog -> { Point[data]}]
```

I would like to know if the `NonlinearModelFit::cvmit` error that `NonlinearModelFit` shows can be removed by (somehow) improving the fit. I tried using some starting values, but I was unsuccessful.

Comment: Setting MaxIterations->100000 doesn't seem to give an error and the speed of the code is not affected.

Comment: Add option `Method->"NMinimize" and MMA evauates withoud message!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann For me, the `NMinimize` method gives a complex-valued fit.  Adding a constraint to the form, `{-a + \[Rho] r^m Cos[m \[Phi] + \[Psi]], r > 0}`, fixes it.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Interesting, v12.2 `NonlinearModelFit[data, -a + \[Rho] r^m Cos[m \[Phi] + \[Psi]], {a, \[Rho], \[Phi], \[Psi], r}, m,Method -> "NMinimize"]` gives a real fit!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I should have mentioned I was using 12.3.

Comment: @HansOlo yes, that works.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann, that also works and I do get a real-valued fit. I am using MMA 12.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are few issues with what you're attempting to do:

- Fitting 6 parameters ($a$, $\rho$, $\phi$, $\psi$, $r$, and the error
  variance) to just 12 data points is usually not enlightening.  (This is not to say that obtaining more data is easy or even possible to do.)
- The parameters estimates for $\rho$, $\phi$, and $\psi$ are not even
  close to being statistically significant.
- The correlation matrix estimate has nearly every correlation equal to 1.  In other words, the model is way overparameterized given the available data.  Predictions might be OK but you should definitely avoid interpreting coefficients (either the magnitude or the sign).

Here is the issue with the parameter estimates:

```
fit = NonlinearModelFit[data, -a + ρ r^m Cos[m ϕ + ψ], {a, ρ, ϕ, ψ, r}, m,
  MaxIterations -> 1000, Method -> "NMinimize"]
fit["ParameterTable"]
```

[image: Parameter table with no restrictions on r]

Here is the issue with the correlation matrix:

```
fit["CorrelationMatrix"] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Correlation matrix]

The model is just overparameterized given the available data.  Note that if one rationalizes the data, only the P-value for $a$ remains statistically significant:

```
fit2 = NonlinearModelFit[Rationalize[data, 0], {-a + ρ r^m Cos[m ϕ + ψ]}, {a, ρ, ϕ, ψ, r}, m, 
   MaxIterations -> 1000, Method -> "NMinimize", WorkingPrecision -> 30];
fit2["ParameterTable"]
```

[image: Parameter table with rationalized data]

```
fit2["CorrelationMatrix"] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Correlation matrix with rationalized data]

Comment: thanks for your answer, I learned a lot from it. From your analysis, it seems like `fit2 = NonlinearModelFit[data, -a + \[Rho] r^m , {a, \[Rho], r}, m, 
  MaxIterations -> 1000, Method -> "NMinimize"]
fit2["ParameterTable"]
` is a better option. I would like to ask you, how many points do you think I should use for the original expression?

Comment: A very loose rule-of-thumb in the biological sciences is a minimum of 20 points plus 5 points for every parameter.  And that results in a bare minimum sample size.  What is "adequate" depends on the subject matter and if you just need to predict or if you need to be able to make reasonable interpretations of the parameters (both size and sign of the parameters).